# sublime text-like code scrollbar on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sublimetext

I have recently switched from Sublime Text to Visual studio code, but there is something that i truly miss, and it is the scroll bar at the top right corner of the which shows a smaller version of the file being edited (I don't know the exact name).

I find it pretty useful to navigate through my files, especially when i want to start deleting blocks of code i have commented out, before i submit my code.

Is there any plugin to get this on visual studio code, or is there any ongoing plans in order to implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracked in this feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4865